# Using OFFSET function across multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets

New to Google sheets, so feel like I'm falling down somewhat of a rabbit hole trying to figure this out...

I have a spreadsheet 'sheet 1' where we keep the details of our sales - Name, address, design, size, tracking.
Then we have `'sheet 2'` set up as a job requirement sheet, this gathers the data to be sent to the manufacturer - like a receipt. But, we only need certain info and only from one row at a time.

I can create the reference cell in `sheet2`, say I select cell `F13` ( where I want my order number ) and type `='sheet 1'!A131`, this gives me the order number from sheet1.
What I would like to do then, is have the other chosen cells change depending on that reference cell.
I have each required information cell with a series of these formulas; `=OFFSET('sheet1'!A131, 0, 6, 1, 1)`, which works...but means every time I change the reference I need to update all of the formulas manually to match the original reference ( say `A131` changes to `A132` ).

I can't use `=OFFSET(F13, 0, 6, 1, 1)`, for obvious reasons it doesn't take into account the formula  address from `'sheet1'`.

Is there a way to get this to work across 2 sheets? I haven't found a way to do it by searching Google, other than the below - but alas I can't understand how to get it to work, kept getting errors.

```
=OFFSET((INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,1,,,"Sheet2")),ROW(),0,,)
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would be to replace the formula in cell `F13` with a [drop-down list](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/186103). Set the cell range of the drop-down list to the column `sheet1!A2:A`. When you have inserted the drop-down list, choose one of the order numbers by clicking the down-arrow ▼ in the cell.

Then replace your `offset()` formulas with `vlookup()` formulas like this:

`=iferror( vlookup($F$13, sheet1!$A$2:$Z, column(sheet1!$B:$B), false) )`

At each instance, replace `column(sheet1!$B:$B)` with a reference to the column where you want to pull the data from.

Comment: Hi doubleunary, thank you so much! This worked exactly how I needed.

Comment: I have the sheet all gathering data as expected, could I possibly pick your brain about one small variation? The area I have for products sold works for one item only, as these will be multiple rows (same column), for example 'order 105' has customers details across one row with the first purchased item in that same row, second purchase drops to the cell below an so on. Is there a way to create a formula that would look at the first product but then offset down one row? Hope that makes sense. Thank you

Comment: Please ask only [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/222741).